# how to access xlsx file that dynamically changes based on current date using R

Tags: r, xlsx, readxl

I have automated few reports which get saved in my local one-drive folder using the below format. (current DateTime gets appended along with the name of the report).

I need to import them in R for further analysis. How to automatically access them based on the current date?

One drive path: C:\OneDrive - CompanyLML\May

```
2021-02-12T08_11_12+00_00Reports Data Status.xlsx
2021-02-13T12_13_12+00_00Reports Data Status.xlsx
2021-02-14T17_02_12+00_00Reports Data Status.xlsx
```

tried the below code but couldn't access them

```
fnam=Reports Data Status.xlsx
fpath='C:\OneDrive - CompanyLML\May'

read.csv(eval(paste(fpath,fnam,sep=""))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Meenu, to read in the current day's xlsx-file, here is some code:

```
#Load libraries
library('tidyverse')
library('lubridate')

# Get today's date
today <- as.character(today())

# Check the contents of the directory
path <- dir('C:\\OneDrive - CompanyLML\\May\\')

# Filter for the xlsx-file that contains today's date
path <- path[str_detect(string=path,pattern=today)]

# Read in as a dataframe
df <- readxl:read_xlsx(path = path)
```